# Django: Should I use protected method _meta in Django?

Tags: django

Lately I've been facing several requirements of getting object data. They can easily be found by accessing protected method `_meta`.
This method has been widely used across the community, but to me it's against the idea of protected method.
Even Jetbrains is complaining about using it.

I'm working with Django admin.

So here are my questions:

- Is it still the case to use it or is it better to not use it?
- Without `_meta`, how do we have equivalent methods such as `get_field`?

I'm trying these on Django 2.0 with Python 3.6

Comment: Django has a page on `_meta` in which it shows use cases: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/meta/#module-django.db.models.options so that seems to suggest it is ok.

Comment: Yes, the _meta API interface is now documented (and has been since 1.8, maybe earlier). Perhaps that underscore is a historical legacy and should be given a name without a leading underscore as an alias?